# Would Microsoft Visual studios C++ 2010 work on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, microsoft

I want to use Ubuntu but I'm not sure if it will work for Microsoft Visual Studios C++ 2010. Or is there another program that will work on Ubuntu that will work just as good (if not better) than Visual Studios?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio would run like death on Ubuntu, but if C++ is your target language, there are way better options out there, many of which are free.

Try **Eclipse**: http://www.eclipse.org/
or **Code::Blocks**: http://www.codeblocks.org/

Both are very popular.

Answer (score 0):

### Visual Studio

As [per Wine HQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892), Visual Studio performs horribly on Wine.

**Visual Studio 2008 (9.0) Express Edition - Bronze**

What works

- Installing using the workaround for Bug #9158.
- Using the IDE to build and generate a DLL.

What does not

- Installing without using the workaround.
- On start the "Visual Studio Explorers and Designers Package" fails to load.
- Build seems to sometimes get stuck at "Generating Code...", restarting the IDE and building again allows you to proceed.

**Visual Studio 2010 Express - Garbage**

What works

- Nothing

What does not

- Everything

**Visual Studio 2010 Professional - Garbage**

What works

- Installer

What does not

- Everything else

**Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - Garbage**

What works

- Open the installer

What does not

- Installing part of Visual Studio 2010

**Visual Studio 2011 Ultimate Beta - Garbage**

What works

- Nothing.

What does not

- Installing with netinstall fails with #(loc.FailedHeader)

---

### Monodevelop

The only other option for opening .sln files on Linux is Monodevelop. Lots of features which you expect in Visual Studio are missing.

Answer (score 0):

For C++ Development on Ubuntu, Eclipse is your best bet, and the easiest way to get the Eclipse IDE is:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 works good with a workaround and it's possible to use the IDE and create a DLL.
Visual Studio 2010 hasn't been tested on Wine 1.4 and 1.5 and doesn't work on Wine 1.3.

**Install instructions for 2008:**

- [Install Wine](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) 1.4 or 1.5
- Create an empty Wineprefix: open a terminal window and enter

`WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.vs2008" winecfg`

- Download Winetricks:

`wget http://kegel.com/wine/winetricks`

- Install .NET Framework 3:

`WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.vs2008" bash winetricks -q dotnet35­`

- Install Visual Studio 2008:

from online installer use this workaround:

`WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.vs2008" _SFX_CAB_SHUTDOWN_REQUEST=1 wine ./vcssetup.exe`

or from CD or ISO:

`WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.vs2008" wine ./autorun.exe`

Source: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=11210

**Install instructions for 2010:**

- [Install Wine](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) 1.4 or 1.5
- Create an empty Wineprefix: open a terminal window and enter

`WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.vs2010" winecfg`

- Download Winetricks:

`wget http://kegel.com/wine/winetricks`

- Install .NET Framework 3:

`WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.vs2010" bash winetricks dotnet20 dotnet40`

- Install Visual Studio 2010:

from online installer use this workaround:

`WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.vs2010" _SFX_CAB_SHUTDOWN_REQUEST=1 wine ./vcssetup.exe`

or from CD or ISO:

`WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.vs2010" wine ./autorun.exe`

Source: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22306

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but if anyone comes here afterwards by means of a Google search, and you don't want to go through the WINE setup...

CodeLite - http://codelite.org - is a great open source, cross platform IDE for C/C++. It is much like CodeBlocks but a lot simpler for beginners and/or new users, and it has an option for opening .sln files for VS projects.

I am sure there are also .sln plugins for CodeBlocks but CodeLite has that already loaded and easy to find. http://codelite.org has every download type including apt links which open up Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: To install Codelite on Ubuntu follow this Q/A: [How to install CodeLite on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/a/330276 "BOEH!!")