# How to install CodeLite on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I would like to install CodeLite on my Ubuntu system, but when I try to install it using the Software Center, it gives me an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiJ0U.png):

```
codelite: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04 is to be installed
          Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but 8c-2ubuntu7 is to be installed
          Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
```

If I try to install these packages trough the console it basically tells me they are already installed:

Command: `sudo apt-get install libgcc1`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgcc1 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10038/discussion-between-blade19899-and-binero)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the [codelite documentation](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/Repositories#toc1), if you have an older version of codelite installed, remove it first, like so:

- `sudo apt-get purge codelite codelite-plugins`

---

The following commands will install the latest `codelite` on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codelite wxcrafter
```

The codelite PPA supports the latest stable versions of Ubuntu, and a few EOL releases, see: [Supported Distributions](http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/dists/).

<sup>**Note**: Trusty currently sports the 2.8v, which crashes when trying to close it.</sup>

### Screenshots

**14.04, with latest codelite**

[image: codelite 8.1.0, Ubuntu Tursty tahr, 14.04]

**14.04**
[image: codelite 6.1 Ubuntu 14.04(amd64)]

**12.04**
[image: codelite 5.2 Ubuntu 12.04(i386)]

**13.04**
[image: codelite 5.2 Ubuntu 13.04(amd64)]

**13.10**

[image: codelite 5.2 Ubuntu 13.10(amd64)]

**Reference**:

- [Howto install the latest codelite in Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/howto-install-the-latest-codelite-in-ubuntu)
- [CodeLite, an open source, cross platform C/C++ IDE | LiteEditor / Repositories](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/Repositories)

Comment: This didn't work for me until I followed the advice in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10038/discussion-between-blade19899-and-binero) of this question to see the suggestion to first remove any key/added repository of codelite from the software center and only then follow the steps in this answer

Comment: I run the code `sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc`but get the error `gpg: WARNING: unable to fetch URI http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc: Server indicated a failure`