# Errors in configuration after Skype installation: libqtgui4:i386,libtiff4:i386,libqt4-declarative:i386,libqtwebkit4:i386,

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, skype, dpkg

I am using the Ubuntu Precise (12.04 LTS).

I have some errors in configuration after Skype (downloaded from the site of Skype) installation.

At this moment I can't install nothing, even using Ubuntu Software Center.

Maybe the source of these errors was that I followed the procedure described in [How to install CodeLite on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330268/how-to-install-codelite-on-ubuntu) to install the Codelite.

I removed the Codelite and its repository ('deb http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ precise universe').

Then I reinstalled Skype.

**But now : the Skype is working, the operating system has configuration errors, and I can't install nothing.**

**Below I am putting the suggestions of solution ("third" block of code)**:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libtiff4
libtiff4: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libtiff4

$ export LANG=C

$ sudo dpkg --purge libtiff4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libtiff4:
 libcupsimage2 depends on libtiff4.
 libpoppler19 depends on libtiff4.
 libtiff4-dev depends on libtiff4 (= 3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5).
 libevince3-3 depends on libtiff4.
 libdevil1c2 depends on libtiff4; however:
  Package libtiff4 is to be removed.
 libgs9 depends on libtiff4.
 libopencv-highgui2.3 depends on libtiff4.
 libtiff-tools depends on libtiff4.
 gimp-plugin-registry depends on libtiff4; however:
  Package libtiff4 is to be removed.
 libcupsfilters1 depends on libtiff4.
 libtiffxx0c2 depends on libtiff4.
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 depends on libtiff4.
 libqtgui4 depends on libtiff4.
 libspandsp2 depends on libtiff4.
 libwxgtk2.8-0 depends on libtiff4; however:
  Package libtiff4 is to be removed.
 libsane depends on libtiff4.
 libmagickcore4 depends on libtiff4.
 gimp depends on libtiff4.
dpkg: error processing libtiff4 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libtiff4

$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqtgui4:i386:
 libqtgui4:i386 depends on libtiff4; however:
  Package libtiff4:i386 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libqtgui4:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-declarative:i386:
 libqt4-declarative:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-declarative:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqtwebkit4:i386:
 libqtwebkit4:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqtwebkit4:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:i386:
 skype:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
 skype:i386 depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36); however:
  Package libqtwebkit4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing skype:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqtgui4:i386
 libqt4-declarative:i386
 libqtwebkit4:i386
 skype:i386

$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-44-generic libunistring0 libwxsqlite3-2.8-0
  linux-headers-3.2.0-44 po-debconf g++ intltool-debian gettext
  nvidia-settings-updates qt4-qmake latex-cjk-xcjk
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic linux-headers-3.5.0-23 libgettextpo0
  wx-common texlive-lang-ukenglish libmail-sendmail-perl
  libsys-hostname-long-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libtiff4:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtiff4:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/143 kB of archives.
After this operation, 501 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 417982 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libtiff4:i386 (from .../libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5_i386.deb     (--unpack):
 './usr/share/lintian/overrides/libtiff4' is different from the same file on the     system
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libtiff4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libtiff4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
$ 

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get -f install

(Reading database ... 417982 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libtiff4:i386 (from .../libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5_i386.deb     (--unpack):
 './usr/share/lintian/overrides/libtiff4' is different from the same file on the     system
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libtiff4:i386 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
$ 


$ sudo apt-get -f install libqtgui4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqtgui4 is already the newest version.
libqtgui4 set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libtiff4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

$ sudo apt-get  install libtiff4:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-44-generic libunistring0 libwxsqlite3-2.8-0
  linux-headers-3.2.0-44 po-debconf g++ intltool-debian gettext
  nvidia-settings-updates qt4-qmake latex-cjk-xcjk
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic linux-headers-3.5.0-23 libgettextpo0
  wx-common texlive-lang-ukenglish libmail-sendmail-perl
  libsys-hostname-long-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtiff4:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/143 kB of archives.
After this operation, 501 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 417982 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libtiff4:i386 (from .../libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5_i386.deb     (--unpack):
 './usr/share/lintian/overrides/libtiff4' is different from the same file on the     system
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Del codelite 5.2-1.precise [21.3 MB]
Del sdformat 1.4.5-1~precise [323 kB]
Del gazebo 1.9.0-1~precise [37.2 MB]
Del wxcrafter 1.2-1.precise [2314 kB]
Del gazebo 1.9.1-1~precise [37.2 MB]

$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libtiff4:i386 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-44-generic libunistring0 libwxsqlite3-2.8-0
  linux-headers-3.2.0-44 po-debconf g++ intltool-debian gettext
  nvidia-settings-updates qt4-qmake latex-cjk-xcjk
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic linux-headers-3.5.0-23 libgettextpo0
  wx-common texlive-lang-ukenglish libmail-sendmail-perl
  libsys-hostname-long-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libtiff4:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtiff4:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/143 kB of archives.
After this operation, 501 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 417982 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libtiff4:i386 (from .../libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5_i386.deb     (--unpack):
 './usr/share/lintian/overrides/libtiff4' is different from the same file on the system
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libtiff4:i386 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

$ sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libtiff4:i386 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
$
```

**The trials until now:**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -f install
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo dpkg --purge libtiff4
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libtiff4
$ sudo apt-get  install libtiff4:i386
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

Trying to get a solution at: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

```
$ sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libtiff4:i386 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

$ sudo apt-get remove libqtgui4:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-declarative:i386 : Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
 skype:i386 : Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: sni-qt:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Could you remove libtiff4 with `dpkg --purge libtiff4` and then again `dpkg --configure -a`, `apt-get install -f`? Please do an `export LANG=C` first, so that the output is in English, in case you want to post it here.

Comment: You have a serious dependency problem. Run the commands one by one, if some fail just update the question, don't use the laters. Install `libqtgui4` with `sudo apt-get -f install libqtgui4`.

Comment: I put there in the third block, the command didnt worked.

Comment: Reading:

ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...s/+bug/1016294

Unmet Dependencies- I am Totally Lost
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/inde...t-2078792.html

Answer (score 1):

Described at:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2171281&page=3

A possible answer:

My interpretation (I readed some comments in the posts about this) of this trouble is that there is a "bug" that makes inviable to run software like Skype:i386 (32-bit programs, because in some moment will appear the unmet dependencies) on the Ubuntu 64-bit. I am sorry about that, because I have a Ubuntu 64-bit and I need to use the Skype.

The indirect solution that solved, for me, the trouble with unmet dependencies was in the way of squakie (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2171281) suggestion:

Using: sudo apt-get build-dep libqtgui4:i386

Resulted in :
Removing skype:i386 ...
Removing libqtwebkit4:i386 ...
Removing libqt4-declarative:i386 ...
Removing libqtgui4:i386 ..

And the using: sudo apt-get build-dep libtiff4:i386

Removed: libqt4-declarative:i386 libqtgui4:i386

So the trouble of unmet dependencies related with :i386 libraries was solved.

But, unfortunatelly, I havent the Skype installed.

Juracy

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall `libtiff4` first so you can remove it:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libtiff4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Braiam, unfortunatelly didnt worked. I put the results in the third block of code of my ask.