# How to recover from failed installment of codelite

Tags: 12.04

My system initially is ubuntu 12.04. I installed codelite yesterday by running "apt-get install codelite", it worked fine. I noticed that it is not the latest version and tried installing the latest manually, but this introduced problem.

I followed the instruction from codelite web page:

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ trusty universe'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codelite
```

But I got dependency error just like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856727/error-while-installing-codelite-ide-in-ubuntu).

I then tried several suggestions, the latest is http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/howto-install-the-latest-codelite-in-ubuntu. But I missed the note about "amd64" and "i386" initially and after I corrected, there still problem.

Anyway, I give up installing the latest version at this point, but I found that I cannot go back now - I uninstalled codelite in the beginning - when I run "apt-get install codelite" again, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codelite : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not installable
            Depends: libwxbase3.0-0 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Could you point me how I can recover from this?

Comment: Try the following: http://askubuntu.com/a/330276/36315

Answer (score 0):

Your error mentions broken packages. I suggest you start with resolving that issue first. Try running apt with the -f flag:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

It may not solve the whole problem, but it would be a good start.