# CodeLite installation missing dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management

ok, this question may seem retarded as there has been so many documentation on this:
Installing CodeLite on Ubuntu 14.04LTS (Trusty Tahr).

I followed exactly the steps in:
http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/Repositories
with special caution to getting the repository right as emphasized in:
http:// forums.codelite.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2914&p=13302&hilit=trusty+install#p13302

```
sudo apt-get purge codelite codelite-plugins
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ trusty universe'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codelite wxcrafter
```

Ok but then I get missing dependencies:

```
 codelite : Hängt ab von: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1) aber 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 soll installiert werden
        Hängt ab von: libhunspell-1.3-0 (>= 1.3.3) aber 1.3.2-6ubuntu2 soll installiert werden
        Hängt ab von: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) aber 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 soll installiert werden
        Hängt ab von: libwxbase3.0-0 (>= 3.0.2) aber 3.0.0-2 soll installiert werden
        Hängt ab von: libwxgtk3.0-0 (>= 3.0.2) aber 3.0.0-2 soll installiert werden
```

Confunsingly, Synaptic shows all packages which are declared missing as installed. Now there has already been this issue in:

[How to install CodeLite on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330268/how-to-install-codelite-on-ubuntu)

However, I have no idea how to find the path to the required packages on

http:// ubuntu.intergenia.de for the wget command as in the solution above.

I would really appreciate your help!
nbt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is strange.
If you take a look at the packages file

```
http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages
```

you will find, that the repository offers `codelite-8.1-1` for trusty. It depends on `libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0)`, which is perfectly fine.

Please make sure you have no other codelite repos in your sources.
Either check under "Software sources" in the Update manager, or issue

```
apt-cache policy | grep codelite
```

Deactivate any other repo than the trusty one and run

```
apt-get update
apt-get install codelite wxcrafter
```

again.

Comment: Yes that was exactly the problem. I ran
`xdg-open /etc/apt/sources.list` and found that repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/vivid universe was still activated besides the trusty universe repository.

Comment: Glad that helped. It's not impossible but unlikely that such a popular repository is broken.